# angular-gettext interpolation in loops

Tags: angularjs, gettext, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to use angular-gettext inside ng-repeat loop?
I'm using angular 1.4.3 and angular-gettext 2.1.0.

Controller:

```
$scope.animals = [{key:'koira',value:'koira'},{key:'kissa',value:'kissa'},{key:'hevonen',value:'hevonen'}];
```

Template:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in animals" translate="">
        <a href="#{{key.key}}">{{value.value|translate}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Po-edit:

```
<a href=\"#{{key.key}}\">{{value.value|translate}}</a>
```

I think Po-edit should do something like this:

```
<a href=\"#{{key.key}}\">koira</a>
<a href=\"#{{key.key}}\">kissa</a>
<a href=\"#{{key.key}}\">hevonen</a>
```

So there is something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

in your controller

```
angular.module(...).controller('YourController', ['gettext'], function('gettext') {
var animalNames = [
  gettext('koira'),
  gettext('kissa'),
  gettext('hevonen')
];
.....
```

In your view :

```
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in animals"> 
    <a href="#{{key.key}}">{{value.value | translate}}</a>  
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Note in your view, the gettext is used as a filter.

The other way to do that is to create a dummy html file which serve nothing but have to store the interpolated text and facilitate the text collection by gulp/grunt whatever you using....

Hope it helps.